# Passing and using an environment in a function

Tags: r, function

I am working with some large data sets and have constructed a negative log likelihood function and associated gradient to pass to an optimisation routine. Both the functions require a vector of parameters and the passing of the large data sets into them.

The optimisation routine will call the two functions multiple times and the speed at which the two functions execute at is most of the bottleneck in the process. I dont want to pass the data directly to function as I was under the impression that some copying by R may occur.

I have considered:

```
# some large data sets
a<-1; b<-2

# place the data sets in an environment
varSpace <- new.env()
assign('c', a, envir = varSpace)
assign('d', b, envir = varSpace)

dFunA <- function(x){
  x <- x + a+b
  x
}

dFunB <- function(x, envir = varSpace){
  x <- x + get('c', envir) + get('d', envir)
  x
}

dFunC <- function(x, envir = varSpace){
  with(envir,{
    x <- x + c + d
  })
  x
}

dFunD <- function(x, envir = varSpace){
  attach(envir)
  on.exit({detach(envir)})
  x <- x + c + d
  x
}


> dFunA(1)
[1] 4
> dFunB(1)
[1] 4
> dFunC(1)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
> dFunD(1)
[1] 4
```

Approach A requires the data sets to be further up the calling stack. It works but I would like a tidier approach.

Approach B requires the use of `get` and calling the environment where the data has been placed.

Approach C doesnt work .

Approach D appears to work but I am mindful of `?detach` which carries the good practice comment `Use of attach/detach is best avoided in functions`.

Any help and advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, copying *may* occur, but probably not, unless you're changing something, as R is copy-on-write.  I'd suggest trying it the simple way and see if it's fast enough, and if not, where exactly the bottle-neck is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to fiddle around with `assign`, `get` or `attach`. Just set the environment for your functions to the one that you've created.

```
dFunA <- function(x)
x + a + b

varSpace <- new.env()
varSpace$a <- 1
varSpace$b <- 2
environment(dFunA) <- varSpace
```

... assuming that this is necessary in the first place. As Aaron commented, R is copy-on-write, so unless you're modifying `a` or `b` they're not likely to be copied.

Comment: interesting will play around with this